# Activation association took too long

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, lenovo

My wifi doesn't connect to any network names, after a day previously it worked fine. My device is Lenovo IdeaPad 3 15ABA7. My wifi modem is Real Tek Semiconductor Kernel Linux image 6.5.0-25 generic Lspci -nnk -d ::0280 Real Tek Semiconductor 10ec:b852 Kernel driver in use rtw89_8852be Kernel modules rtw89_8852be, rtw_8852be

I have many kernel modules installed do not know which one to blacklist: rtw89 core, rtw89pci, rtw_8852b. Now I do not know which module to blacklist with modprobe.d blacklist...
I have disabled ipv6 on my router changed it to 802.11n

Non of related articles work for my situation

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.

Comment: Unfortunately I did 


sudo sh -c 'echo "blacklist rtw89_8852be" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf' now it doesn't see modem, I deleted driver... could you please help to remove all wifi related conf, modprobe.d and etc I want to install from git lwfind rtw